# Translating magento into swiss german

Tags: germany

I would like to install a second language on an existing site.this language is swiss-german(ch_de).
I downloaded an existing package but is only version beta.what is the difference with a stable version?

Secondly after installing my new view, only the internal elements were translate.all my pages, category, products have not been translate.comment should I do to perform the translation.

Comment: You need to perform translation which have not been translated by extension.

Comment: ok but how do I? I saw the need to create the CSV file

Answer (score 1):

Beta version means that not all strings (words, phrases) have been yet translated.
The categories, products, cms blocks and cms pages need to be manualy translated in the backend. When editing a category or product, you can see a store view chooser in the top left corner of the content area. From there you can select for which store view (language), you want to edit the names and descriptions
[image]

When creating a CMS page or block, you can select the storeview on which it will display, thus you can create a separate page or block for each language

Comment: ok i understand.To translate the missing elements of the beta version, is there a way to do.in the site tree I saw that there were csv files?

Comment: yes, you can use magento's inline translation tool http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/inline-translation-in-magento/

Comment: ok thank you i will look.And for the additional modules, how it goes for translation?should I create csv files?

Comment: you can create csv files, or use the translation tool

Comment: ok so how the module will link with the file csv.Should it call a particular name?

Comment: yes, the csv file name is declared in module's config xml file. each module should come with a predefined csv file for english, so you can copy that into your new language folder, and start translating

Comment: ok thank you, i have two last question too.in csv file, how do I find the missing translation because I'm on a beta version?and to translate existing products and category I saw that you could use files from imports.how does this work?